# Is brute force trial the only approach to find smallest k such that (840k + 3) is a multiple of 9?

Tags: divisibility, gcd-and-lcm, prime-factorization, least-common-multiple

The following is the answer approach given for the below problem in my old book. I am skeptical about the brute trial approach suggested (though k is found after 2 trials in this case). Is there a proper and better method in which we can find the least positive k in this case such that **(840k + 3)** is divisible by 9? (*Regret the low-quality image*)

[image]

Comment: $840k+3 = (93\times 9 + 3)k + 3$

Comment: If you're fine with above, it shouldn't be hard to figure out when $3k+3$ is divisible by $9$

Comment: @rsadhvika But again, though simple, it's a trial method to find when 3k + 3 is divisible by 9, isn't it? Say, won't trial be a risky approach when the numbers are larger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $9\mid(840k+3)$ then we have
$$840k+3\equiv0\mod{9}$$
$$3k+3\equiv0\mod{9}$$
$$3k\equiv-3\mod{9}$$
$$\therefore k\equiv-1\equiv2\mod{3}$$
Hence $k=2$ is the smallest such positive integer $k$. All solutions are of the form $k=2+3n$ where $n\in\mathbb{N_0}$.

Comment: Thanks for the precise answer. But though I can intuitively see how you went to "mod 3" from "mod 9" and divided both 3k and -3 by 3, can you please tell me the Number Theory theorem or corollary which is applied in this case? Any online reference for that theorem or corollary will be very helpful.

Comment: We have that $$ax=ay\mod{b}\implies x\equiv y \mod{\frac{b}{\gcd{(a,b)}}}$$

Comment: That settles it. Thanks for taking the time to answer questions of mathematical noobs like me :-)

Comment: You can also look at it as factoring out: $$3k\equiv -3\bmod 9\implies 3k=9z-3=3(3z-1)\implies k=3z-1=3(z-1)+2$$